# How can the R location be customized for RStudio

Tags: r, macos, osx-mountain-lion, rstudio

I previously used homebrew to install R and the package installer for RStudio.  Recently I started using Boxen, which takes over homebrew.  I had to re-install R from source using homebrew, and it now exists in my Boxen Cellar location.  Now RStudio no longer launches, saying "Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations".  I tried reinstalling RStudio (I needed to upgrade anyway) but that didn't help.  It doesn't even open for long enough to let you specify a custom location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I figured it out finally.  Discovered from [this post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R) that you can set RSTUDIO_WHICH_R to your custom location.  On Mountain Lion, this is most easily done with:

**For OS X Mountain Lion 10.8:**

```
echo setenv RSTUDIO_WHICH_R [your custom bin path]/R | launchctl
```

Another option is to set a softlink from /usr/local/bin to the custom R path, but the above seems like a better solution.

---

#### Edit: For newer macOS versions:

```
launchctl setenv RSTUDIO_WHICH_R [your custom bin path]/R
```

But after a restart `launchctl` has forgotten the environment variable again.
Therefore a LaunchAgent-.plist for launchctl must be created.
[Instructions could be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/8057078)

Comment: just a note. The original site is closed.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up deleting the alias file "R" from /usr/bin/ In this way, I don't have to set the RStudio environment variable every time. From http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/versions_of_r

Rstudio looks first in /usr/bin/R and then on /usr/local/bin/R, where I have the new version of R installed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
1. First install R 3.2.0 binary for Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and higher at http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/
2. Then run R
3. Then run RStudio