# R version doesn't support quartz graphic device - RStudio won't plot

Tags: r, macos, homebrew, rstudio, quartz-graphics

I'm running Mac OS Maverick.

In my previous setup, the plots would correctly display on the plot tab on RStudio.
I reinstalled R with `homebrew` and, when I use RStudio, it gives me the following warning

> WARNING: The version of R you are running against does not support the
>   quartz graphics device (which is required by RStudio for graphics).
>   The Plots tab will be disabled until a version of R that supports
>   quartz is installed.

When I plot something, it opens up the `XQuartz` app on my mac. It does display the graphs (sometimes with weird colors though), but I'd really like it to plot in RStudio itself.

Is it that `homebrew` has a version of `R` that doesn't support the quartz graphics device or have I messed up something elsewhere?

As always, any help will be very much appreciated.

---

Some details of my setup:

- R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
- RStudio Version 0.98.1091
- Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit). Mac OS 10.9.5
- I installed `R` with `homebrew` the following way

  `brew tap homebrew/science
  brew install r`
- Previously I had installed `tcl/tk` the following way

  `brew tap homebrew/dupes
  brew install tcl-tk --with-tk`

Comment: The maintainers of the Mac fork of R don't support homebrew (or MacPorts). There is an Archive of the Mac-SIG-R Mailing list that has the rationale.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2014-October/011186.html

Comment: Is this the same question in essence? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128859/how-can-the-r-location-be-customized-for-rstudio

Comment: @BondedDust, thanks for the links. However, I don't understand the implications. Is it your understanding that right now the homebrew version does not support quartz? That would be an appropriate answer for my question.

Comment: @BondedDust, I don't think it's a related question. That person is asking about the search path for RStudio and I don't have any issue with that (I only have one version of R installed right now).

Comment: Please report those issues on the Homebrew/Science tracker where we can usually fix them promptly. The error you're seeing is due to a mistake when packaging the prebuilt binaries. It's being fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run into the same issue.

According to the [R brew formula history](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commits/master/r.rb) the last bottled version (i.e. precompiled version, which is what is installed by default) isn't run against aqua due to some [bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commit/a7a7f46fd68ada46a4193fafc8f825c68ff1ce40) so the installation of R has no aqua capabilities, which is what RStudio graphics device requires.

After trying to understand the formula logic I figured that if built from source:

```
brew install r --build-from-source
```

it would compile with clang (check `brew --env`) and therefore correctly build against aqua. It takes a little longer to install but it worked for me. To check, from the terminal open R and see `capabilities()` aqua should be `TRUE` for RStudio's graphics device to work.

Comment: thanks a lot! That solved my issue and I'm sure it'll be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using homebrewed R and Rstudio on Yosemite. I ran into the same problem, probably after I had updated R from ver. 3.1.2 to ver. 3.1.2_1.

My ad-hoc solution is

- to `brew uninstall R`, and
- to install R from CRAN.

RStudio display graphs inside its window when I use CRAN version of R. However, this is not the best solution to me, because I love to manage all unix packages using homebrew to avoid possible conflicts.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I had R from CRAN before and things were working fine. I did not like installing tcl/tk from the R CRAN package and that's why I tried using the brew version (same reason as you: avoiding conflicts). It would be great if somebody could confirm whether the `brew` version of `R`supports `quartz` or not.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too. I previously had homebrewed R installation with a working quartz graphic device, which comports with others in this thread who suggest that an update to homebrew's R script caused the problem.

I can confirm that daniel's answer works. I tried `brew install r --build-from-source` and `quartz()` has stopped throwing errors.